# Given the expression of the matrix find the adjoint and the square of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

> Let the matrix $U=\mathbb{I}-ww^* $ with $w\in\mathbb{C}^3$ being a column vector, find the expression for $U^*$ and for $U^2$.

So for the adjoint $U^* $ I gave it a try and got $U^* =\mathbb{I}-(ww^* )^* =\mathbb{I}-w^*  w$ but my book says $U^* =U$, how is that possible?

And for $U^2=(\mathbb{I}-ww^* )(\mathbb{I}-ww^* )=\mathbb{I}-2ww^* +ww^* ww^* =\mathbb{I}-(2-ww^* )ww^* $ but I don't know how else to continue nor if this is right.

Answer (score 2):

Recall the product rule for adjoints:
$$ (AB)^* = B^*A^*\ . $$ Can you use this to see what you did wrong in your calculation for $U^*$? Otherwise, take a look here:

> $$U^* = \Bbb I - (ww^*)^* = \Bbb I - (w^*)^*w^* =\Bbb I - ww^* = U\,. $$

Your calculation for $U^2$ seems to be correct.

**EDIT:** Here' why your result and the book's result are equivalent:
$$ U^2 = \Bbb{I} - 2ww^* + ww^*ww^* = \Bbb{I} - 2ww^* + w(w^*w)w^* = \Bbb{I} - 2ww^* + w\|w\|^2w^* = \Bbb{I} - 2ww^* + \|w\|^2\,ww^* = \mathbb{I}-(2-\|w\|^2)ww^*\ . $$

Comment: That's right, my bad. But onto $U^2$, my book ends up with $U^2=\mathbb{I}-(2-||w||^2)ww^* $, how do they get there? I know $w^* w=||w||^2$ but how do they get to that point?

Comment: Yeah, why? Let me see that quick calculation please, I'm guessing it has to do with $w^*w=(w,w)$ (with $(,)$ being the inner product) by the definition of the Hermitian inner product but I don't know how to continue

Comment: **EDIT:** Also isn't $ww^*$ equal a 3x3 matrix while $w^* w$ equals a 1x1 (scalar)?

Comment: no it doesn't, $ww^*$ is a 3x1 times a 1x3, according to matrix multiplication, that outputs a 3x3 matrix